# Batch executing of stored procedure with Spring JDBC API

Tags: java, oracle, spring, stored-procedures, jdbc

Is it possible to execute stored procedure using Spring JDBC API in batch mode?

I tried to use Spring JdbcTemplate's method batchUpdate and it doesn't work.
I use Spring 3.0 and Oracle JDBC driver version 11.2.0.3

```
   JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    template.batchUpdate("BEGIN SCHEMA.PERSON_UPDATE(I_N_PERSON_ID=> ?  ,I_S_NAME=> ?  ,J_N_TID=> ?);END;", 
                new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                    public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                        OracleCallableStatement cs = (OracleCallableStatement) ps;
                        cs.setString(1, persons.get(i).getName());
                        cs.setLong(2, persons.get(i).getPersonId());
                        cs.registerOutParameter(3, OracleTypes.NUMBER);
                    }

                    public int getBatchSize() {
                        return persons.size();
                    }} 
                );
```

Thanks

Comment: And how exactly it doesn't work?

Comment: I cannot register OUT parameters of procedure because of Exception : PreparedStatement cannot be cast to oracle.jdbc.internal.OracleCallableStatement

Is there any way to register OUT parameter?

Comment: And why do you need OUT parameter here - I can't see any result handling in your code. As you can use only prepared statements here and not callable statements - you can either remove OUT parameter from procedure or write wrapper function and select it from dual. Then you could replace OracleCallableStatement with PreparedStatement and have no problem

Comment: OUT parameter is needed to be retrieved from procedure because of latter using in code. 

What do you mean by wrapper function?

Comment: Did you look at CallableStatementCreator API: http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.0.x/api/org/springframework/jdbc/core/CallableStatementCreator.html#createCallableStatement(java.sql.Connection)?

Comment: @vlcik I mean a PL/SQL function that will exec your procedure and return OUT parameter value as function result. Then you can execute a prepared statement like `select func_person_update(?,?) from dual`

Answer (score 0):

There is a mistake in implementation of the method `setValues`. You create instance of `OracleCallableStatement` but you have to register parameters in `PreparedStatement` which given in method argement like `ps`

```
JdbcTemplate template = new JdbcTemplate(dataSource);

    template.batchUpdate("{call SCHEMA.PERSON_UPDATE(?, ?)}",
            new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
                public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                    ps.setString(1, persons.get(i).getName());
                    ps.setLong(2, persons.get(i).getPersonId());
                }

                public int getBatchSize() {
                    return persons.size();
                }
          }
    );
```

But there is a problem. `PreparedStatement` doesn't work with out parameters.